# Let $a_n\ge0$ be a sequence. Sufficient conditions of $(a_n)$ such that $\lim {1\over n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of non-negative reals. I want to know conditions on $(a_n)$ such that $\lim {1\over n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k$ exists. I know that if $\lim a_n$ exists, then the above limit exists with $$\lim {1\over n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k=\lim a_n$$

I also find that if there are finitely many sub-sequential limits of $(a_n)$ (say $l_1,\ldots,l_m)$, then $$\lim {1\over n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k=\frac{l_1+\cdots+l_m}{m}$$

Is there any other relaxed sufficient condition on $(a_n)$ (like boundedness etc.) to guarantee the existence of the limit?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Look up [Cesàro summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation)

Comment: I do not know the answer to your question. The only thing I'd like to remark is that boundedness is not enough. You can construct a sequence of zeros and ones which is not Cesàro summable. Pick very long blocks of ones until the mean is almost one, and then a very long block of zeros until the mean is again almost zero.

Comment: I think we're almost there; in addition to boundedness of $(a_n)$, we perhaps just need the differences $( a_n - a_{n-1} )$ to also be bounded and then apply Stolz-Cesàro with $b_n = n$.

Comment: @TomChen I am a bit confused. If $(a_n)_n$ is bounded, then $(a_n -a_{n-1})_n$ is bounded too, isn't it?

Comment: Consider the sequence $1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,\dots$. in which every fourth entry is $-1$ while the others are $1$. This sequence has only two limit points $1$ and $-1$, but the limit of  the Cesaro sums is $\frac 12$, not $\frac{1 + (-1)}2 = 0$ as you claim.